# How can I get content of variable to print onto the custom .php/.html page?

Tags: php

Basically, what I want to achieve is getting value of variable onto the custom page.
For example, I've following code:

```
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {
        $message = urlencode("File you've chosen is already uploaded.");
        echo $message;
        die;
    }
```

Now to get you more familiar with what I want is following:

Is it possible to create one custom file (page) (php/html) that contains "standard content" and by standard content I meant something static and print out the value of `$message` in one of the divs instead of just getting white page with content of message?

I know that I can achieve this with putting custom html inside of every `if` with content of `$message`, but I think there's more elegant way of getting the same result with at least 500 lines of code less?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a template engine? Twig is one such option: https://twig.symfony.com/ Blade is another one: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade (also available standalone) - a third one is Foil: https://foilphp.github.io/Foil/ - and you'll find plenty more if you search a bit after "template engine PHP" (btw; `urlencode` is meant for content that goes into a URL, not for general escaping; you usually use `htmlentities` for that - but more generally; a template engine will handle it for you automagically. (and in this case you control the value completely, so no real need))

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the name (template engine) and thanks for the references, this is exactly what I was seeking for. I am going to do the update with this now. I have this solution currently with `urlencode` currently because previously I was using `header("Location:" . $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] . "?message=" . $message);` to get error message onto  current page that I am onto, but I realized that it's going to be a problem because when I do more uploads, perhaps first upload is okay I get "Everything ok", after the second upload output will be `"Everything ok ?message= Everything ok"... `

Comment: Anything using `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` is a _big_ problem to begin with. Do not expect that value to always be filled, or be filled "correctly." Do not _rely_ on it for any functionality.